# Make POST request to my index route fetch API

Tags: javascript, django, post, fetch

In my `"/"` route I have a form with an input textarea field, when the form is submitted, it should dynamically show the content of the textarea, without reloading the page. I'm trying to implement this with fetch API on my Django app. I'm working on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

I have two problems:

1. With the code down here, the console.log doesn't print anything, and If I change `response.json()` for `response.text()`, I'm getting the whole html code, not the thing I want to fetch
2. I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2` in my js console when posting the form

This is my js code:

```
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = (event) => {


  fetch("", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      body: document.querySelector('#new_message').value
    }),
    headers: {
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      // Print result
      console.log(result)

      let div = document.createElement('div')
      div.innerHTML = (result.body);
      div.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid lightblue; padding: 10px; margin: 5px;";

      document.querySelector('#posts').append(div);
      document.querySelector('#new_message').value = ""
  });
  event.preventDefault();

}
```

The POST method is being sent to the server, but the console throws this uncaught error. `#new_message`is my textarea field id

Comment: Is that the same code? See how the path is in fetch (`""`)

Comment: Openthe actual request in browser dev tools network and see that what is sent is as expected and what is in the response body

Comment: @AksJacoves It's the same route

Comment: @charlietfl What do you mean by that?

Comment: F12 in browser opens the developer tools. Then go to network tab and isolate the xhr requests and open the one you are making

Comment: I'm getting what I wrote in the form in json format @charlietfl

Comment: Not really sure what that means or what part you are seeing that. Should see request/form data section, and response/body sections. What browser are you using?

Comment: Im using google chrome. I'm seeing this in the Request PayLoad part of the network tab @charlietfl

Comment: Ok and there is a response section also. Sounds like request payload is as expected so what about the response? Also what is `status` of the whole request...should be 200

Comment: Sorry to respond late. The status code is 200 @charlietfl

Comment: Ok so am still not sure which end of this is having the parse error but it is almost always something wrong in the response body. The fact that the character is a `<` usually means there is html there

Comment: Yeah, tht'a why when I parse it as text it throws html code